# Android Studio Webview (Java) - Is there a way to wait until a loading inside a web page is finished before loading url?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview, android-webview-javascript

I'm trying to get some elements in a web page using `webView.loadUrl(...);`.
However, I found out that there is a loading that "creates" these elements after the page is already loaded. So, I didn't find a way to get these.
I tried to use `onPageFinished` but it doesn't look like it is called when the loading inside the web page finishes.
I also tried to put a button that triggers the `webView.loadUrl(...);`. This tip only works if the user doesn't click too fast on the button, because then the loading doesn't have the time to finish before. 
Here is a video of the page booting up, hoping for you to better understand what I mean by a loading  inside the page :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1267dcJai8&feature=youtu.be

If I haven't been clear enough, I'd be happy to clarify things further.
Thank you in advance! 
**Edit :** To clarify something, I'm not exactly asking for a way to get these elements. A way to delay the `webView.loadUrl(...);` while the webpage is loading would also be perfect for me.

Comment: where is the video ?

Comment: Here is the link of the youtube video : [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1267dcJai8&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 0):

Try onProgressChanged() of WebChromeClient like below.

**Documentation link:**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onProgressChanged(android.webkit.WebView,%20int)

```
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, final int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

                   if (newProgress == 100) {
                       //Page load done
                   }
                   else
                   {
                      //Page is still loading wait...
                   }

            }
```